# What does "switch to the heart of" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "switch to the heart of" mean in the following sentence?

> Why? There are women in the orchestra; people indifferent to a women’s charms. Besides, how many times would you be enraptured by appearances? After all, it’s something you tire of, and **switch to the heart of the question.** Statistically, of course, there are women conductors.
>
> -- [*www.newyorker.com*](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/culture/2013/10/women-gays-and-classical-music.html)

Does it imply, "as you get older you won't care about the looks of women and more about deep stuff like their ways of thinking or life experiences"?

Comment: What is it about the sentence that confuses you? It is easier to give a good answer if we know where the question is coming from.

Comment: thank you. "switch to the heart of.." I don't understand it in this context...

Comment: Good. That's helpful. Edit that into your question. Presumably you've looked up or already know the meanings of the separate words. (If not, [go do so](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/)). Show what research you've done, and tell us why it doesn't make sense *to you in this context*. Keep in mind, this isn't intended to be mean-spirited or cruel. Stack Exchange is all about good questions and answers, and the more information you can give us about your question, the better the answers can be.

Comment: It seems like the quotation is missing the initial question, which the interviewee is evading. The *heart* of the question is whether women can conduct, not about whether the orchestra would be actually distracted by an attractive woman.

Answer (score 1):

As cited here, it's impossible to say what *switch to the heart of the question* means. But checking OP's link, we quickly see that the writer here is *switching to (turning to, addressing, responding to)*...

> "In your opinion, could a woman conduct?" *(to which the writer's interviewee replies, **"No!"**)*

That's the general question. As to what exactly the "heart" of that question is, I can't really say. But it's bordering on Lit Crit - grammatically one should assume the heart of the question is *"How do you explain the fact that women conductors exist, if you say women can't conduct?"*, because that's what he asks, after saying he's going to switch to the heart.

But logically I'd have thought the heart of the matter was *"How on earth can you justify claiming that women are incapable of conducting?"*.

Comment: I don't think it borders so much on LitCrit as on TranslCrit. This is the second piece OP has given us today which was translated by "a Russian-speaking friend". "Switch to the heart of the matter" again suggests a fairly literal translation of a foreign idiom. We have no way of telling whether the switch is supposed to be a consequence of tiring or an injunction to the interviewee.

Comment: -1 for egregious misreading of “it’s something you tire of, and switch to the heart of the question”, which meant that people switch focus from appearances to substance.

Comment: @jwpat7: I don't understand what you mean there. OP asks what *switch to the heart of the question* means. Logically it makes little sense to say "the question" is embodied in the statement that follows. You might say it's *"Why?"* at the start of the excerpt cited by OP (which is effectively my final sentence), but I think it's nonsense to suggest that "the question" is something being addressed by *audiences* as they switch from appearances to substance. It's obviously something that the writer asked the conductor earlier in the interchange.

Comment: I disagree with what you say in the last 3-4 lines of your comment; but I won't argue further, as the translation is too poor to bear more analysis than given so far, if that much.

Comment: Noting StoneyB's comment as well, I think it's clear any interpretation is likely to be "subjective", whether we classify it as LitCrit, TranslCrit, or whatever. But I seriously doubt OP is actually asking *"What does **switch to the heart of the question** mean in a general sense?"* To be honest, if [Kit's comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11008/what-does-switch-to-the-heart-of-mean/11011?noredirect=1#comment18562_11008) had been there before I answered, I'd have probably upvoted the comment and closevoted the question.

Answer (score 1):

First the speaker says that women should be beautiful<sup>1</sup>. Then he says that their beauty would be distracting<sup>2</sup>.

Then the interviewer asks why someone would be distracted. There are women in the orchestra who would not be distracted by another woman.

Then the language becomes a little odd, probably since it's a translation.

It might be better translated as:

Appearance is something that doesn't continually hold your focus. Eventually you switch to the important part of the issue<sup>3</sup> which is the conducting. After all there are women conductors.

I don't think that the quote is referring to someone tiring over years, but rather something that doesn't last during a performance. Women have proven their ability to be conductors and there is no reason to think that their appearance continually causes the orchestra to be distracted.

<sup>1. The important thing is, a woman should be beautiful, likable, attractive.</sup>
<sup>2. Musicians will look at her and be distracted from the music.</sup>
<sup>3. heart of the question</sup>